# Role of Item Key in Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

In Zabbix every item has several defining characteristics like Name, Type, Data Type, etc. One of these properties is "[Item Key](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/item/key)". But in the [Zabbix's documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/item/key) nothing is mentioned about it's use. I wanted to know why in Zabbix every item has a key (other than the name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched more and I understood that in Zabbix an item is identified in two different ways:

- A human friendly name: using Name of the item
- An agent friendly name: Zabbix-Agent should have a way to know what do you want from it to fetch. This is done using "Item Keys". There are plenty of [predefined "Item Keys"](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/items#zabbix_agent) (platform-dependent). You can also define your own "Item Key".